# combine multiple conditions in if-statement

Tags: powershell, if-statement, boolean-logic

How do you chain 4 conditions together when you want either ONE set or the OTHER set of 2 condiitions to be true?

To be more precise I want to do:

If User is logged in AND Operating system version is Windows 10

OR

User is logged in AND LogonUI process is not running

Don't bother with the commands, they all work correctly when isolated, my issue is chaining them together.

For example I have :

```
if (
        (Get-WmiObject –ComputerName $poste –Class Win32_ComputerSystem).UserName`
        -and`
        (Get-WmiObject -Computer $poste -Class Win32_OperatingSystem).Version -like "*10*"
    )
    { echo do X }
```

which is working fine. I want to add within that same `if` the other block of conditions. I tried this, but it's not working:

```
if (
        (Get-WmiObject –ComputerName $poste –Class Win32_ComputerSystem).UserName`
        -and`
        (Get-WmiObject -Computer $poste -Class Win32_OperatingSystem).Version -like "*10*"`
        -or`
        (Get-WmiObject –ComputerName $poste –Class Win32_ComputerSystem).UserName`
        -and -not`
        (Get-Process -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ComputerName $poste -name logonui)
    )
    { echo do X }
```

How do you chain multiple "blocks" like this? I know I could do two different IF, I had it working but isn't there a way to chain it all together in one IF? (the IF contains a lot of code and i don't want to duplicate it with two IF)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Put each set of conditions in parentheses:

```
if ( (A -and B) -or (C -and D) ) {
    echo do X
}
```

If *either* the first *or* the second set of conditions must be true (but not both of them) use `-xor` instead of `-or`:

```
if ( (A -and B) -xor (C -and D) ) {
    echo do X
}
```

Replace A, B, C, and D with the respective expressions.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make the code in your own answer easier to understand you can remove the duplicate code to make the `if` statement cleaner.

Assigning the results to variables and using those instead:

```
$UserName = Get-WmiObject –ComputerName $poste –Class Win32_ComputerSystem | select -ExpandProperty UserName
$WindowsVersion = Get-WmiObject -Computer $poste -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | select -ExpandProperty Version
$LogonuiProcess = Get-Process -name logonui -ComputerName $poste -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Then either:

```
if (($UserName -and $WindowsVersion -like "*10*") -or ($UserName -and -not $LogonuiProcess)) {Write-Output "do X"}
```

Or

```
if ($UserName -and $WindowsVersion -like "*10*") {Write-Output "do X"}
elseif ($UserName -and -not $LogonuiProcess) {Write-Output "do Y"}
```

Answer (score 0):

So after trying a few things, it seems there are two methods:

```
if (
        (Get-WmiObject –ComputerName $poste –Class Win32_ComputerSystem).UserName`
        -and`
        (Get-WmiObject -Computer $poste -Class Win32_OperatingSystem).Version -like "*10*"`

    ) { echo do X }

    elseif (

        (Get-WmiObject –ComputerName $poste –Class Win32_ComputerSystem).UserName`
        -and -not`
        (Get-Process -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ComputerName $poste -name logonui)

    )   { echo do X }
```

or using Ansgar Wiechers's excellent answer to chain it all in one IF:

```
if (
        (      
        (Get-WmiObject –ComputerName $poste –Class Win32_ComputerSystem).UserName`
        -and`
        (Get-WmiObject -Computer $poste -Class Win32_OperatingSystem).Version -like "*10*"`
        ) -or`
        (       
        (Get-WmiObject –ComputerName $poste –Class Win32_ComputerSystem).UserName`
        -and -not`
        (Get-Process -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ComputerName $poste -name logonui)`
        )

    ) { echo do X }
```